# Where was my documentation moved to?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

I clicked a link in my user profile to a documentation topic that I had written previously. This gave me an error message: "Linked example has been moved; view prior to move". But there is only a link to the old topic. What I'd really like to know is where this has been moved *to*, so that I can update it, or so that people I have sent the link to can see it.

To clarify, I think this is a bug or poor design. Usually if something is moved, links to the old location should redirect to the new location. And why does my user profile only show the original link but not the moved link, when both are attributed to me?

URL: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/88/streams/11976/closing-streams

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: type "closing streams" into the tag specific so docs search box.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks. If the only way to find something, after clicking the link from my user profile, is to then search for it, then that seems like a bad design... updated this question to reflect that. I'm not sure if this should get [bug] or [feature-request] tag...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fair observation; if you try it now, it is slightly different:

[image]

Better?

Comment: Why would anyone be interested to view it prior to the move?  I think you are confusing the UI.   Keep only the changes you made and that is "moved here".

Comment: @JonH because you presumably got there via a link, so you might want to see what the person linking you expected you to see; but mostly I left it because I wasn't involved in the discussion about showing that link in the first place! Changing "moved" to "moved here" (as a link) seemed like a pragmatic change I could make without having to track down people in different timezones as me :)

Comment: Much better, through if I may feel free to suggest something, perhaps write "has been moved to <topic-name>" instead of "here".

Comment: @bwoebi then we get a few issues relating to layout and space, but that would probably be more useful; also, I don't actually have the proper name at this point, without some tweaks

Answer (score 5):

You are here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/110/inputstreams-and-outputstreams/11976/closing-streams#t=20160811163036307379

Comment: Would be helpful to explain how you got that link, and how people can replace parameters for future users with this question.

Comment: @Goose i got it simply by using the search within docs.  Remember the elastic search is pretty narrow for docs as it works for the topic you are in to present results. I searched for closing streams and it came up.

Comment: As an aside, docs isn't yet crawlable by google, but if you use a site specific search (so.com/documentation) you can use google to look for docs material.